# ora-00911 problem to create two tables in ORACLE

Tags: oracle

> ORA-00911: invalid character Rextester uses '' as a delimiter.

Try replacing ';' with '' Try to create 2 tables, but there are mistake . I am using 'rextester com' to compilate it, but can't find there is mistake?

```
 DROP TABLE TV\\      
   CREATE TABLE TV (name VARCHAR2(40), brand VARCHAR2(10),
                                     diagonal NUMBER(2), technology VARCHAR2(15), 
                                     sizetv NUMBER(10),  brightness NUMBER(4), 
                                     powertv NUMBER(3),  price NUMBER(6) )\\;    
TRUNCATE TABLE TV\\;   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES (‘SonyKD-75X9405C’, ‘Sony’, 75, ‘затворная’, 192*104*32, 565, 264, 471000)\\;   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES (‘PanasonicTX-65CZR950‘, ‘Panasonic’, 65, ‘поляризационная’, 145*92*31, 216, 201, 918000)\\;   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES (‘PanasonicTX-58DXR800’, ‘Panasonic’, 58, ‘затворная’, 138*83*36, 531, 99, 195000)\\;   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES (‘PanasonicTX-65DXR900’, ‘Panasonic’, 65, ‘затворная’, 146*89*33, 950, 220, 330000)\\;   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES (‘SonyKD-65XD9305’, ‘Sony’, 65, ‘затворная’, 146*89*28, 480, 157, 229000)\\;   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES (‘SamsungUE65KS9590’, ‘Samsung’, 65, ‘-‘, 144*92*38, 1189, 110, 235000)\\;   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES (‘LG 65UF950V’, ‘LG’, 65, ‘поляризационная’, 146*90*25, 268, 115, 230000)\\;   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES (‘PanasonicTX-65DXR780’‘Panasonic’, 65, ‘затворная’, 145*90*36, 454, 108, 209500)\\;    
INSERT INTO TV VALUES (‘Philips65PUS8700’, ‘Panasonic’, 65, ‘затворная’, 156*91*27, 281, 163, 179800)\\;   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES (‘Philips65PUS6521’, ‘Philips’, 65, ‘-‘, 146*90*26, 346, 155, 131100)\\;   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES (‘PanasonicTX-65CXW704’, ‘Panasonic’, ‘затворная’, 146*89*40, 416, 145, 146500)\\;   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES (‘SamsungUE60JU6850’, ‘Samsung’, 60, ‘-‘, 136*83*37, 344, 199, 101800)\\;   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES (‘TelefunkenXU65A441’, ‘Telefunken’, 65, ‘поляризационная’, 146*90*34, 239, 118, 70000)\\;   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES (‘TCLU58578065’, ‘TCL’, 58, ‘-‘, 131*83*28, 262, 78, 50000)\\;   

SELECT * FROM TV\\;   
SELECT * FROM TV WHERE price > 170000\\;   

   
DROP TABLE TVAccessory\\;   
CREATE TABLE TVAccessory (name VARCHAR2 (35), brand VARCHAR2(15),  
                                                      type VARCHAR2(20), guarantee VARCHAR2(10),
                                                      material VARCHAR2(7), color VARCHAR2(11),
                                                      price NUMBER(5) )\\;   
TRUNCATE TABLE TVAccessory\\;   
INSERT INTO TVAccessory VALUES (‘Microsoft XBOX 360 250gb’, ‘Microsoft’, ‘Игровая консоль’, ‘1год’, ‘АБС’, ‘белый’, 45590)\\;   
INSERT INTO TVAccessory VALUES (‘Samsung  DVD-C450K’, ‘Samsung’, ‘DVD плеер’, ‘6 месяцев’, ‘пластик’, ‘черный’, 1395)\\;   
INSERT INTO TVAccessory VALUES (‘Sony PlayStation 3 Super Slim 500gb’, ‘Sony’, ‘Игровая консоль’, ‘1год’, ‘АБС’, ‘белый’, 14099)\\;    
INSERT INTO TVAccessory VALUES (‘LG DVX - 490H’, ‘LG’, ‘DVD плеер’, ‘6 месяцев’, ‘пластик’, ‘черный’, 3290)\\;   
INSERT INTO TVAccessory VALUES (‘Acer E4W Silver’, ‘Acer’, ‘3D-очки’, ‘3 месяца’, ‘пластик’, ‘черный’, 1990)\\;   
INSERT INTO TVAccessory VALUES (‘Gal AR-170 Black’, ‘Gal’, ‘Антенна телевизионная’, ‘1год’, ‘Сталь’, ‘серебристый’, 1990)\\;    
INSERT INTO TVAccessory VALUES (‘ДУ One For All Contour TV’, ‘One For All’, ‘Пульт’, ‘1год’, ‘пластик’, ‘черный’, 990)\\;   

SELECT * FROM TVAccessory\\;   
SELECT * FROM TVAccessory WHERE price > 1900\\;
```

Comment: This is same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/64592708/5292302?. You need to adress the comments that you had on that.

Comment: Does your original SQL have the exact characters from your example? Oracle does not like the curly "smart quotes" that some text editors insist on using. Make sure the quotes around the literals are the single non-curly quote mark. Also, the backslashes before the semicolons shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

After quite a few replaces (single quotes, double backslashes), fixed column datatypes and lengths, missing values, enclosing `sizetv` into single quotes - success!

The 1st table:

```
DROP TABLE TV;      
CREATE TABLE TV 
  (name       VARCHAR2(40), 
   brand      VARCHAR2(10),
   diagonal   NUMBER(2), 
   technology VARCHAR2(40),    -- instead of 15
   sizetv     VARCHAR2(10),    -- instead of NUMBER
   brightness NUMBER(4), 
   powertv    NUMBER(3),  
   price      NUMBER(6) 
  );    
TRUNCATE TABLE TV;   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES ('SonyKD-75X9405C', 'Sony', 75, 'затворная', '192*104*32', 565, 264, 471000);   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES ('PanasonicTX-65CZR950', 'Panasonic', 65, 'поляризационная', '145*92*31', 216, 201, 918000);   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES ('PanasonicTX-58DXR800', 'Panasonic', 58, 'затворная', '138*83*36', 531, 99, 195000);   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES ('PanasonicTX-65DXR900', 'Panasonic', 65, 'затворная', '146*89*33', 950, 220, 330000);   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES ('SonyKD-65XD9305', 'Sony', 65, 'затворная', '146*89*28', 480, 157, 229000);   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES ('SamsungUE65KS9590', 'Samsung', 65, '-', '144*92*38', 1189, 110, 235000);   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES ('LG 65UF950V', 'LG', 65, 'поляризационная', '146*90*25', 268, 115, 230000);   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES ('PanasonicTX-65DXR780','Panasonic', 65, 'затворная', '145*90*36', 454, 108, 209500);    
INSERT INTO TV VALUES ('Philips65PUS8700', 'Panasonic', 65, 'затворная', '156*91*27', 281, 163, 179800);   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES ('Philips65PUS6521', 'Philips', 65, '-', '146*90*26', 346, 155, 131100);   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES ('PanasonicTX-65CXW704', 'Panasonic', null, 'затворная', '146*89*40', 416, 145, 146500);   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES ('SamsungUE60JU6850', 'Samsung', 60, '-', '136*83*37', 344, 199, 101800);   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES ('TelefunkenXU65A441', 'Telefunken', 65, 'поляризационная', '146*90*34', 239, 118, 70000);   
INSERT INTO TV VALUES ('TCLU58578065', 'TCL', 58, '-', '131*83*28', 262, 78, 50000);
```

The 2nd table:

```
DROP TABLE TVAccessory;   
CREATE TABLE TVAccessory 
  (name      VARCHAR2 (35), 
   brand     VARCHAR2(15),  
   type      VARCHAR2(50),       -- instead of 20
   guarantee VARCHAR2(20),       -- instead of 10
   material  VARCHAR2(20),       -- instead of 7
   color     VARCHAR2(30),       -- instead of 11
   price     NUMBER(5) 
  );   
TRUNCATE TABLE TVAccessory;   
INSERT INTO TVAccessory VALUES ('Microsoft XBOX 360 250gb', 'Microsoft', 'Игровая консоль', '1год', 'АБС', 'белый', 45590);   
INSERT INTO TVAccessory VALUES ('Samsung  DVD-C450K', 'Samsung', 'DVD плеер', '6 месяцев', 'пластик', 'черный', 1395);   
INSERT INTO TVAccessory VALUES ('Sony PlayStation 3 Super Slim 500gb', 'Sony', 'Игровая консоль', '1год', 'АБС', 'белый', 14099);    
INSERT INTO TVAccessory VALUES ('LG DVX - 490H', 'LG', 'DVD плеер', '6 месяцев', 'пластик', 'черный', 3290);   
INSERT INTO TVAccessory VALUES ('Acer E4W Silver', 'Acer', '3D-очки', '3 месяца', 'пластик', 'черный', 1990);   
INSERT INTO TVAccessory VALUES ('Gal AR-170 Black', 'Gal', 'Антенна телевизионная', '1год', 'Сталь', 'серебристый', 1990);    
INSERT INTO TVAccessory VALUES ('ДУ One For All Contour TV', 'One For All', 'Пульт', '1год', 'пластик', 'черный', 990);
```

Result (in SQL*Plus) (I'm posting counts as my database doesn't speak ... Russian?):

```
SQL> SELECT count(*) FROM TV WHERE price > 170000;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         9

SQL> SELECT count(*) FROM TVAccessory WHERE price > 1900;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         5

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you for help, now i  have  all  tables, but do you know,  what kind  of  problem is  now?ORA-06550: line 32, column 75:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: yep  lines  32,39,47,54

Comment: What I meant to say was: when you executed code, which line represents line 32? What's written in that line? The whole code I posted contains 44 lines, so ... I have no idea where did lines 47 nor 54 come from.

Comment: https://rextester.com/QKZZJO75735 there is nothing  on line  32, i  can't understand  how to  fix  it

Comment: Code on Rextester is **NOT** what I posted above. It is not line #32 that makes problems, but all INSERT statements into the 1st table. SIZETV should be enclosed into single quotes, while one line misses DIAGONAL value. I wonder why did I spend time fixing that code for you, if you're using something completely different. I believe I'll give up.